# Passwordless ssh does not work with multiple servers

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, jenkins

I have a jenkins server that runs a job to ssh (passwordless) out to Server A and runs a script. This works very well and I set it up by doing:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on Jenkins
2. Copy over the `id_rsa.pub` from Jenkins to Server A (I have manually added it to authorized keys and did a `ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub`, both seem to work)
3. SSH from Jenkins to Server A successfully without a password

What I can't seem to do is copy that same behavior on Jenkins to Server B using the exact same keygen, copy, and ssh. The only thing that I do different is I give the id_rsa a different name like `id_rsa_x.pub` to not overwrite the existing one. I also tried changing the location of the public key to authorized_keys2 but looking in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that appears to be disabled by default. I'm not sure why this behavior is happening since everything I seem to google would point to this being the proper way to do it.

I assume it's either a sshd_config misconfiguration or the fact that my Jenkins server is CentOS 6.9 and ssh version (OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013) and Server A and B are CentOS 7.4. I'm unable to do a `ssh -v` or `ssh -v localhost` to get the versioning of those two servers.

(I'm trying to figure out how to add my `sshd_config` on here but everything is turning it large and bold)

Comment: If you want to use different private/public keypairs or identities for different services, give them different filenames on the local machine, and specify which to use on connection with the `-i` option (`-i /path/to/identity/file`).  Better is to customize per host in your `~/.ssh/config` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't repeat the keygen. That will regenerate the key and break access to server A.

Do the keygen initially, from there run the copy id command to all the servers and you should be good to go.

In summary, only run keygen **once** :

1. Run ssh keygen
2. Run ssh copy id to server a
3. Run ssh copy id to server b
4. Run ssh copy id to server c
   And so on :)

Comment: Just to be clear, part of that is simplifying. Use the same key, no point having multiple. Try with the method in my answer and see if it works